# ES6 re-exported values are wrapped into Getter

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Can somebody explain this to me? Let's say I have these two modules:

```
// moduleTwo.js

export const module2Func = () => {
  return 2
}
```

And

```
// moduleOne.js

export * from './moduleTwo'

export const module1Func = () => {
  return 1
}
```

And then I import *moduleOne* somewhere:

```
import * as final from './moduleOne'

console.log(final)
```

Then final results into something likes this:

```
{ module2Func: [Getter], module1Func: [Function: module1Func] }
```

Why is `module2Func` wrapped into a `Getter`? It is the `export from` that syntax does that? All functions work as expected. I'm using Babel 6 to transpiler code.

Thank you for any kind of explanation!

Comment: That's likely Babel's doing to implement live bindings of module imports.

Comment: should that by import at the top of moduleOne?

Comment: when you use `import * as final` you still need to reference `final` like so:
`final.module2Func`, if you dont want to do this you can do:
`import { module1Func, module2Func } from './moduleOne'`:
http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's Babel's doing to correctly implement [reference binding of module imports](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_imports-are-read-only-views-on-exports). You can [look at the compiled output](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=export%20*%20from%20'foo'%3B&playground=true).

Input:

```
export * from 'foo';
```

Output:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _foo = require('foo');

Object.keys(_foo).forEach(function (key) {
  if (key === "default") return;
  Object.defineProperty(exports, key, {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function get() {
      return _foo[key];
    }
  });
});
```